# How to scan and display the expired products in an inventory system

Tags: c#

We're making an inventory system which should display the list of products that will expire within 5 days. I don't know how to explain this clearly but I'll do my best. What's on my mind is it should scan all the records and those who will expire within 5 days will be displayed. What should I use to do this, should I use the for loop, if else. Thank you. The language I'm using is c#.

here's what I've done so far.

```
public void all()
    {

        SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
        DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

        MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=christina\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=cafe_inventory;User ID=sa;Password=tina;");

        MySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);

        //Clear the datatable to prevent duplicate generation of data in gridview.
        p_table.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["empinfo1"];
        m_da.Fill(p_table);
        // Clear the ListView control
        //listView3.Items.Clear();


        // Display items in the ListView control
        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];

            // Only row that have not been deleted
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                // Define the list items
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["bnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pnum"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["pname"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["descr"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["dater"]).ToShortDateString());
                //lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["exp"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(((DateTime)drow["exp"]).ToShortDateString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["qt"].ToString());

                // Add the list items to the ListView
                listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }

    }
```

-->this will display all the products.

Comment: Let us see what you've done so far

Comment: are you using database?

Comment: yes, I'm using MS SQL 2008. @SudhakarTillapudi

Comment: @christina: check my answer below., if you need something else let us know

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi on my database exp's datatype is date, there's an error which says it's incompatible with tinyint.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi sorry, I'm new here. :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
string query = "select * from inventory where Exp
                       < (Select DATEADD(day,5,@CurrentDate))";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@CurrentDate ,CurrentDate);
SqlDataAdapter m_da = new SqlDataAdapter(command , MySqlConnection);
```